# How to combine on each element while response code from the php script and radio button is checked javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try to achieve validation on multiple input elements.

**Here is my HTML**

```
<input class="date_of_birth" name="date[]" type="text" />
<span class="stepbirthVal"></span>
<input class="livingkid" type="radio" name="livingkid[]" value="1">Yes
<input class="livingkid" type="radio" name="livingkid[]" value="0">No

<input class="date_of_birth" name="date[]" type="text" />
<span class="stepbirthVal"></span>
<input class="livingkid" type="radio" name="livingkid[]" value="1">Yes
<input class="livingkid" type="radio" name="livingkid[]" value="0">No

<a href="javascript:;" id="stepbirth" class="btn disabled">Next</a>
```

At the moment my code only check for the input field, but i want to combine it with radio button. Like when input is filled in it does not have response code 0 and radio button is checked, it has to look always both conditions if one of the is not correct remain Next button disabled.

**This is my JS code**

```
var livingkid =  [];
 $('.livingkid:checked').each(function(){
  livingkid.push($(this).val());
  });
//GET JSON from Validation.php and extract the nodes
  var response = xmlhttp.responseText;
  var parseJson = JSON.parse(response);
  var resultCode = parseJson.code;
  var resultMessage = parseJson.message;

  //Remove disabled class from the next step button
  var element = document.getElementById('stepbirth');
  element.classList.toggle("disabled", parseJson.some(function (resp) {
    return !resp.code;
  }));
  //Show Validation Message
  var items = document.querySelectorAll(".stepbirthVal");
  parseJson.forEach(function (response, i) {
    return items[i].innerHTML = response.message;
  });
```

How can i validate here with this classList.toggle each radio button is checked and response code = 1? else Next button remain disabled.

I hope you guys understand my question.

Thanks in advance.